# Windows 7 Pro "shutdown /h /d u:6:12" Does Nothing

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

On Windows 7 Pro x64, why does

`shutdown /h /d u:6:12`

causes the shutdown command to display its usage help (as though I had typed the command with no arguments or with the `/?` argument).

This command is in a script that my UPS software runs when there is a power failure.  The arguments `/d u:6:12` indicates an unexpected environmental power failure.

Comment: Wonder if you cant use `/d` with `/h`?

Comment: Well, hibernating a computer because of a power failure seems like a common action.  And the command documentation makes no mention of mutual exclusivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*And the command documentation makes no mention of mutual exclusivity*. Well that is not completely true. From the help you see

```
/h         Hibernate the local computer.
           Can be used with the /f option.
```

And alternate sites the following descriptions appear

1. "Hibernate the local computer (only with /f )" [Source](http://ss64.com/nt/shutdown.html)
2. "This can only be used with the /f option " [Source](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/rtrent/archive/2009/08/28/shutdown-exe-switches.aspx)

Also if you read the description of `/d` it only mentions that you have to **provide the reason for the restart or shutdown.**

Yes... *hibernating a computer because of a power failure* is a good reason... however the power failure is from the UPS and not the computer itself which is what those codes are meant to address. While the above is not conclusive it does coincide with the issue you are having. You could always manual set an event yourself to simulate the behavior you are looking for.

[Create an event log on command line](http://www.windows-commandline.com/create-event/)